# PHP Catchable Fatal Error - on server

Tags: php, apache, symfony, composer-php, silex

Currently facing an issue with a new Silex (Symfony) PHP application. If I start it locally like `php -S localhost:8080` everything works fine right away. I directly get an 500 Internal Server Error with the following log output after uploading it on the server:

```
[Tue Jan 19 16:15:24 2016] [error] [client 62.99.210.9] PHP Catchable fatal error:
Argument 2 passed to Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Event\\FilterControllerEvent::
__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Event\\callable,
instance of Closure given, called in /appl/www/htdocs/XXX/static/dashboard/php/
vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php on line 131 and defined in /appl/www/htdocs/XXX/static/dashboard/php/
vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Event/FilterControllerEvent.php on line 35
```

**composer.json:**

```
{
    "require": {
        "silex/silex": "~1.2",
        "twig/twig"  : "1.*",
        "symfony/twig-bridge": "2.1.*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "php/vendor"
    }
}
```

Any ideas on what causes such an error appreciated.

PHP Version: PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Oct 23 2014 06:58:46)

Comment: what version of php do you have installed locally and on server?

Comment: PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Oct 23 2014 06:58:46)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Callable type hint is available since PHP 5.4

> Callbacks can be denoted by callable type hint as of PHP 5.4. This
>   documentation used callback type information for the same purpose.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

What's happening here is PHP tries to resolve type hint "callable" to class name and since there is no namespace provided it looks for a class "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\callable" which obviously doesn't exist.

Comment: Sure, BTW: You probably know that already but for future generations: If you cannot change PHP version on the server, you can restrict required version of the PHP in composer.

Comment: How can I do restrict require a version of PHP using composer?

Comment: just use `"php" : "5.3"` for example. It won't downgrade your packages to version compatible with particular version of PHP but will force proper development environment. It's a little dirty approach (I would prefer that composer uses packages in correct version than prevent you from installing them at all on never version of PHP) but it's the only way besides setting proper version for each package separately.

Comment: Okay so this is for development purpose only - so I can be sure that my development stack also will work on the server. It won't allow me to "hidden upgrade" PHP? Is there anyway beside updating PHP on the Server to run the app at all?

Comment: The problem with making sure that your development env perfectly reflects production is not so trivial. In your case you have legacy version of PHP and I'm presuming that it's not running on instance that is fully managed by you. Fortunately upgrading PHP won't beak your code (upgrade to PHP7 can be risky but also easy to test in advance). If you have composer.lock file in place and don't use `composer update` command on production, all dependencies that were set in the lock file on your local environment will be preserved on the production, just use `composer install`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101103/discussion-between-adam-and-dominikangerer).

Answer (score 0):

I use php 5.3.9 and i have the same problem
Silex in 1.3.3+ versions install HttpKernel what use PHP 5.4+ features.

My solution is use Silex 1.3.2. All dependecies use PHP 5.3.x
I don't use require PHP 5.3 because composer need 5.4 for work.

The easy way is update the php version but i can't update server. You know